# Minimum voltage to ionize Xenon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, orbitals, ionization-energy

As we know, the ionization energy for Xenon is $12.13 \,\rm{eV}$. Is this  value obtained via experiment? Or can it be calculated? In the latter case, can you please share the formula? I tried to use

$$\Delta E =  R_H \left(\frac{1}{n_f^2} - \frac{1}{n_i^2} \right)$$

taking $n_f = \infty$ and $n_i = 5$th orbit, as  valence electrons are  in the $5 p$ orbitals.

Could you please correct me here? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calculation you describe is the energy required to remove an electron from the $n=5$ orbital of a [hydrogenic atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom) i.e. an atom that contains only a single electron. Clearly this isn't applicable to a Xenon atom because it contains $54$ electrons not just one.

For a hydrogenic atom the wavefunction can be calculated exactly because it is a two body problem, just the electron and the nucleus, and the equation describing this is straightforward. As soon as we introduce extra electrons life becomes far more complicated. Now the $5p$ electron feels not only the attraction due to the positive nucleus but the repulsion to the other $53$ electrons.

Calculating the wavefunction for a polyelectronic atom cannot be done analytically, but it is straightforward to calculate using numerical techniques. Typically we would start by using a [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) approximation then refine it using a technique like [configuration interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_interaction). These allow us to calculate quantities like the ionisation energy to high precision.

So the $12.13$ eV ionisation energy can both be calculated and of course measured experimentally. However the calculation has to be done numerically and there is no simple equation like the one you quote.

Comment: A walkthrough of the calculation would be very nice.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: there isn't a simple walkthrough because it's a complicated calculation. The Wikipedia article I linked is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 There are plenty of 'walkthroughs' available - just choose your favourite introductory textbook on atomic physics or quantum chemistry; the relevant walkthrough will take up about 50-70% of the book.

Comment: That said, I'm not completely sure that something as big as xenon can be fully calculated in an *ab initio* way without turning to pseudopotentials to incorporate the effect of relativistic corrections on the inner core.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Those are generalised, so they take up more space. Plus, they're explaining the reasoning behind it, not just the application of the formulae. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hartree-Fock.png) followed by [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/65edaeb6bbaea75b6d06325664cb94b18912d8c4) wouldn't take up _that_ much text, would it? Although, it _is_ [tag:quantum-mechanics]...